# transfer java to c++

Tags: java, c++

In Java

```
public int compareTo2(String that) {
    String sig1 = this.sort();
    String sig2 = that.sort();
    return sig1.compareTo(sig2);
}
```

In C++

```
int compareTo2 (string that) {
    string sig1 = this.sort();
    string sig2 = that.sort();
    return strcmp(sig1,sig2);
}
```

The first is a Java program. I translated it to C++ program. Did I write it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Best way to know: type it, try to compile it, try to run it ;-)

Comment: "Did I write it correctly?" - "No." - That was easy. What's next?

Comment: @sellibitze, that was condescending.... and not helping

Comment: IMO its much easier to go from C++ to Java =P...seriously tho, type it and compile it

Comment: `that.sort()` I didn't know that Java strings had a `sort` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that with `string` you talk of `std::string`:

`std::string` doesn't provide a member named `sort`. You shall do that with `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(sig2.begin(), sig2.end());
```

And `strcmp` is thought to be used with `const char*`s, so you have to write:

```
return strcmp(sig1.c_str(), sig2.c_str());
```

Finally, `this` has to be dereferenced:

```
std::string sig1 = this->sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

- `this` is a pointer, so it has to be dereferenced with `this->item_I_want`.
- `this` is usually optional in a C++ class anyway; the compiler knows what you mean with `item_I_want` when in a method.
- There is no `sort()` method for [C++ strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).
- `strcmp()` requires C strings (`char*`); you can call it with `strcmp(sig1.c_str(),sig2.c_str())`.
- Better approach for string comparison in C++ is simply `sig1 == sig2`, which returns a boolean.

Comment: concerning the 5th point: maybe he wanted the behaviour strcmp, that the index of first mismatch is returned?

Comment: @Polybos I wasn't really sure what his intentions were.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to determine if two strings that have their individual characters sorted alphabetically are equal.

Neither of your functions will work as you are doing some weird stuff.

1. `java.lang.String` does not have `sort()`. You have to turn the String into a `char[]` and then sort that array and then turn it back into a `String`.
2. `std::string` in C++ does not have `sort()`. You have to use `std::sort()`
3. `std::string` in C++ can be compared with `==`
4. You are calling `this.sort()` in Java...what's `this`?

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` does not take a string; you would need use

```
strcmp(sig1.c_str(), sig2.c_str());
```

In order to sort your strings you need to `#include <algorithm>` then you can call

```
std::sort(sig1.begin(), sig1.end());
```

to sort your strings.

I would also recommend that you use the `strncmp()` method and give a max length. It is much safer than `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

No -- at least probably not. First of all, `std::string` doesn't have `sort` as a member function, so you'd probably use `std::sort` instead. Second, you can't pass an `std::string` to `strcmp`. You can either use the `c_str` member function, or just compare the strings directly using normal operators (though that only gives a two-way comparison, not the three-way result of `strcmp`). Third, your code seems to depend on inheriting from (or otherwise extending) the standard string class, which is rarely a good idea.

```
bool compareTo2(std::string a, std::string b) { 
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    return a < b;
}
```

Edit: Note that this takes the slightly unusual step of passing the strings by value. We need a copy of the original string so we can sort it without modifying the original anyway, so I just passed by value to get a copy, then sorted the copy we received as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For something vaguely similar to what was given:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

int compareTo2(string s1, string s2) {
    string s3, s4;
    std::copy(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter<std::string>(s3));
    std::copy(s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter<std::string>(s4));
    std::sort(s3.begin(), s3.end());
    std::sort(s4.begin(), s4.end());
    return s3.compare(s4);
}

int main() {
    compareTo2(std::string("abc"), std::string("cba"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be as loyal to the Java semantics as possible, maybe your should implement your method as:

```
int compareTo2 (const string& that) const
{
    string sig1 = this.sort();
    string sig2 = that.sort();
    return strcmp(sig1.c_str(), sig2.c_str());
}
```

Anyway, when using STL algorithms, you will have to implement the "is-less-than" semantics on your sort algorithms:

```
bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) const
{
    return s1 < s2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like others have said, `strcmp` is not what you want.

`string` already has a method that does that:

```
sig1.compare(sig2)
```